# setTimeout without delay on first run?

Tags: jquery

I have this function and I'd like to execute it in the first time without wait the timeout 5000.

How can I execute the setTimeout function without delay the first time?

```
function slideSwitch() {

    var $gallery = $('#slideshow'),
    $active = $gallery.find('img:visible'),
    $next = $active.next().length ? $active.next() : $gallery.find('img').first();

    setTimeout(function() {

        $active.hide();
        $next.fadeIn('1000', slideSwitch);

    }, 5000);

};
```

Comment: Do you mean `setInterval`? `setTimeout` only runs once. Or do you only want it to run twice?

Answer (score 1):

Define a function rather then anonymous function and before setTimeout call it.

```
function fnc ...

fnc();
setTimeout(fnc, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the `setTimeout` call after the hide/fade actions:

```
function slideSwitch() {
    var $gallery = $('#slideshow'),
        $active = $gallery.find('img:visible'),
        $next = $active.next().length ? $active.next() : $gallery.find('img').first();
    $active.hide();
    $next.fadeIn('1000', () => setTimeout(slideSwitch, 5000));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function slideSwitch() {

var $gallery = $('#slideshow'),
$active = $gallery.find('img:visible'),
$next = $active.next().length ? $active.next() : $gallery.find('img').first();
var fooBar = function() {

    $active.hide();
    $next.fadeIn('1000', slideSwitch);

};
fooBar();
setTimeout(fooBar, 5000);
};
```

Comment: You might want to offer some explanation as well.